# EditText stays behind the keyboard for some android device

Tags: listview, android-listview, android-edittext

I'm using a listview containing several EditText in my android app.
used in manifest.xml

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
```

and java code:

```
et_email.setOnFocusChangeListener(new CustomOnFocusChangeListener());

private class CustomOnFocusChangeListener implements OnFocusChangeListener {
    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
        if (hasFocus) {
            getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_VISIBLE);
        }           
    }
}
```

So lost focus problem was solved. But I encountered a problem like this:
EditText stays behind the keyboard for android device version 4.1.2 of samsung galaxy s3 and note 10.1 tablet. No problem with another device with Android version 4.1.2 and android version 4.3 with galaxy s3.
I tried hard but could not solve the problem.

Edit:
This is screen layout:

```
 <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 android:background="@color/White"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/ll_passengersInfoScreen"    
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

<ListView
  android:id="@+id/lv_details”   
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent">
</ListView>

 <TextView
   style="@style/TextViewWhiteBoldLargeSize"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:padding="@dimen/padding_medium"
   android:text="@string/Guest_Info"/>

<ListView
  android:id="@+id/lv_passenger"   
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:dividerHeight="1dp"
   android:divider="@color/Black">
</ListView>


     <LinearLayout 
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:baselineAligned="false"
   android:orientation="horizontal">

    <!— several view more -!>          

    </LinearLayout>

  </LinearLayout> </ScrollView>
```

Edittexts into the "lv_passenger" listview row. I calculate the height of the listView dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I also faced the same problem...

I have to changed the root ViewGroup as ScrollView and then removed the "adjustPan" from the manifest file.

In your case, You need to remove the "adjustPan" from the manifest and try to get the focus on touch item.

Hope it will help you to solve your problem.

Comment: I removed the "adjustPan" and used root ViewGroup as ScrollView but this time staying in EditText above and does not appear when typing. Only if I remove the "adjustPan" becomes the focus problem.

Comment: Try to use "adjustResize".Check whether it solves your problem or not?

Comment: I tried "adjustResize" but edittext stays above for android version 4.1.2 but as I said before, it's working android version 4.3